# Execute synchronize module in Ansible automation platform results in file not found

Tags: ansible, automation

Recently we switched to Ansible automation platform 2.3. My execution environment is **ee-supported-rhel8** which contains the Ansible.posix.synchronize module.

When I execute a  synchronize module it is failing with:

"src: /tmp/memo.txt no such file".

It was running in Tower 1.2 without any issue.

```yaml
    - Name: Install rsync on the Target
      package:
        name: rsync
        state: present
    
    - Name: Synchronize file from local to remote   
      synchronize:
         src: /tmp/memo.txt
         dest: /temp/test
```

Error

> "cmd": `"/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /tmp/memo.txt root@xyz1234:/tmp/test"`,

> "msg": "Warning: Permanently added 'xyz1234,148.168.65.73' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
> \r\nWARNING!\n                          This system,…
> For additional information consult your local business's employee
> privacy notice or contact your local Privacy Officer. \nrsync:
> link_stat "/tmp/memo.txt" failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous
> errors) (code 23) at main.c(1189) [sender=3.1.3]\n",

I kept the source file in both control node and execution node it is still failing.

I also kept the source in a separate remote server. That is also failing. It is throwing error both source and target cannot be in remote.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

AAP uses execution environments which are containers. If /tmp/memo.txt is not known to the container the task will fail.

If the files to sync are part of the project that includes the playbook then it is present inside the container. If the files / folder to sync reside elsewhere, you need to delegate that task(s) to that source system where they reside that you want to sync.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

The error says:

> rsync: link_stat "/tmp/memo.txt" failed: No such file or directory

Short answer: The file */tmp/memo.txt* is missing on the controller.

---

Details: The first [example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#examples) shows how to use the module

```yaml
- name: Synchronization of src on the control machine to dest on the remote hosts
  ansible.posix.synchronize:
    src: some/relative/path
    dest: /some/absolute/path
```

For example, the below play

```yaml
- hosts: test_01

  tasks:

    - package:
        name: rsync

    - synchronize:
        src: /tmp/memo.txt
        dest: /tmp/test
```

synchronizes the file */tmp/memo.txt* on the controller to the file */tmp/test* on the remote host *test_01*. Given the file on the controller

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/memo.txt
test rsync
```

make sure the file is synchronized to the remote host

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_01 cat /tmp/test
test rsync
```

The error can be reproduced by removing the file */tmp/memo.txt* from the controller:

> fatal: [test_01]: FAILED! => changed=false
> cmd: /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --rsync-path='sudo -u root rsync' --out-format='<>%i %n%L' /tmp/memo.txt admin@test_01:/tmp/test
> msg: |-
> Warning: Permanently added 'test_01' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
> **rsync: [sender] link_stat "/tmp/memo.txt" failed: No such file or directory** (2)
> rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.2.7]
> rc: 23

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir for the direction.
Actually I can execute this piece of code using ansible-playbook command.
But when I am trying to execute it from AAP GUI platform its giving me the no Such file error. I put the source file in Controller Node as well as Execution Node. But nothing worked . My guess is since it is running from Container based EE it is looking in that container but just a guess. I want to execute this simple task from AAP platform but not happening as of now. Looking for your advice. Both Ansible-playbook command and Execcution environment has same version ansible

Comment: An awful lot of words here. Is the file present or not?

Comment: Sorry ..Yes the file is there ..if you notice my first post in the bottom I mentioned that the file is present in both controller and execution node.

Comment: @Prade: what were you using before you *switched to Ansible* where the rsync worked?

Comment: @Greg Tower 1.2 and now switched to AAP 2.3

Comment: I suspect it is looking for the file inside the container not in the localhost unlike in Tower. If there is any method to use synch in AAP pls suggest